# VB.NET Menu can't find items with slash

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm new to ASP.NET and I was asked to change the label of one entry in our menu. A very easy task. The problem is that the new value contains a slash **"/"** and now sentences like this:

```
MyMenu.FindItem("XXX/YYY")
```

cannot find the menu element.

When there's no slash, the code works correctly; for instance when I replace the slash with a dash. Unfortunately I have to make it work with a slash.

EDIT:

**MyMenu** is a **System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu**

The sitemap file contains this line

```
<siteMapNode url="SomePage.aspx" title="XXX/YYY" description="Some Description" />
```

The original label was completely different. If for testing purposes I replace in both parts **"XXX/YYY"** with **"XXX-YYY"** or **"XXX YYY"** it works correctly.

Comment: Can you show a little more code?  What Type is `MyMenu`?

Comment: @TLS more information added. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/` is the default `pathseparator` for the WebControls.Menu object.  `FindItem` matches the menu items by the full path, so when you put a `/` in the name of the menu item, it's thinking that it needs to traverse a path.  It can't find a menu item named "YYY" under a menu item named "XXX", so it finds nothing.

Try setting the `pathseparator` property to something that is not used in the menu items, such as a comma `,` or a pipe `|`.

[MSDN Menu.PathSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.pathseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)